# Are m-dissipative operators closed (II)?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

Let $X$ Banach space. As mentioned in the answer to question

[Are m-dissipative operators closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4588119/are-m-dissipative-operators-closed)

a dissipative operator $A \colon D(A) \subset X \to X$ is closed if and only if there is $\lambda_0>0$ such that $R(\lambda_0 I-A)$ is closed (hence $R(\lambda I-A)$ is closed for every $\lambda>0$). This implies that if $A$ is m-dissipative (i.e. dissipative and $R(\lambda I-A)=X$ for some $\lambda$) then it is closed.

This is in contradiction with [R. Philips, DISSIPATIVE OPERATORS AND HYPERBOLIC SYSTEMS OF PARTIAL DIFFERENTIAL EQUATIONS] where at p 201 in the footnote 6 the author provides an example of a maximally dissipative operator on a Hilbert space which is not closed.

Where is the problem? In Hilbert spaces m-dissipativity is equivalent to maximally dissipativity.

Comment: Do you have a reference for "In Hilbert spaces m-dissipativity is equivalent to maximal dissipativity"?

Comment: Yes please see [Barbu, V. (2010). Nonlinear differential equations of monotone types in Banach spaces. Springer Science & Business Media ] in particular Remark 3.1, p.10 .

Comment: @S.Maths do you have any hint?

Comment: Thanks. I just got the book, no clue for the moment.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4763989/is-a-dissipative-closed-operator-maximal-dissipative, where I posed a related question. Think the answer to your question is given there.