# Is a dissipative closed operator maximal dissipative?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

This is a follow up to the following questions about m-dissipativity:

[Are m-dissipative operators closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4588119/are-m-dissipative-operators-closed)

[Are m-dissipative operators closed (II)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4590270/are-m-dissipative-operators-closed-ii)

Is a dissipative closed operator $A:D(A)\subset X\rightarrow X$ in the Hilbert space $X$ maximal dissipative?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is No. For maximal dissipativity we need $A$ dissipative and the range of $\lambda I -A$ should coincide with $X$ for some $\lambda>0$. This is the case if $0$ is in the resolvent set of $A$, i.e. if $A$ is a closed and boundedly invertible operator.

Requiring closedness results in the range of $\lambda I -A$ being a subset of $X$.